# Mi group by me da más resultados de los que debería

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, group-by

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener el país mas rico de cada continente, pero solo el mayor de cada continente (solo deberian aparecer 7 registros) y aquí me aparecen todos.

Esto es lo que he tratado:

```
SELECT country.name, country.Continent, MAX(GNP) FROM country GROUP BY Continent ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Comment: Bieenenido, muestra el código que trataste, revisa [ask] saludos

Comment: El codigo es este: SELECT country.name, country.Continent, MAX(GNP) FROM country GROUP BY Continent ORDER BY 3 DESC

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon ese código arriba, para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Hola, podrías decirme si te sirvió el código que te puse

Answer (score 0):

Para que un group by funcione correctamente debe cumplirse que lo que no este en el group by debe aparecer en el select como una función de agregación y en tu caso tienes a country.name sin la función de agregación, prueba esto

```
select max(country.name) as pais, country.continent, max(gnp) as máximo 
from country
group by continent
order by 3 desc;
```

Ahora todo aparece en el select con una función de agregación prueba y me dices